# org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanWiringInfo.BeanWiringInfo is initialized with null name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, aspectj, spring-session

I'm trying to re-wire an `@Autowired` field after a session serialization to  Redis using Spring Session and Aspectj.

This is the bean:

```
@UIScope()
@SpringComponent(value = AboutView.VIEW_NAME)
@SpringView(name = AboutView.VIEW_NAME)    
//
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME, value = AboutView.VIEW_NAME, dependencyCheck = false, preConstruction = true)
public class AboutView extends AbstractView {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "butterfly-effect-frontend-system:about";

    private Table tableFrontEndInformation;

    private GridLayout backendLayout;

    private GridLayout frontendLayout;

    @Autowired
    private transient DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
```

This bean is using @Configurable and the name of the bean definition (value). Unfortunately the aspect is creating a `BeanWiringInfo` with null bean name, that will raise an error as the name is required.

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME, value = AboutView.VIEW_NAME, dependencyCheck = false, preConstruction = true)
```

The error happens due the following constructor which is called by AnnotationBeanWiringInfoResolver

```
/**
     * Create a new BeanWiringInfo that points to the given bean name.
     * @param beanName the name of the bean definition to take the property values from
     * @param isDefaultBeanName whether the given bean name is a suggested
     * default bean name, not necessarily matching an actual bean definition
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the supplied beanName is {@code null},
     * is empty, or consists wholly of whitespace
     */
    public BeanWiringInfo(String beanName, boolean isDefaultBeanName) {
        Assert.hasText(beanName, "'beanName' must not be empty");
        this.beanName = beanName;
        this.isDefaultBeanName = isDefaultBeanName;
    }
```

The AnnotationBeanWiringInfoResolver instantiates the BeanWiringInfo from this code:

```
protected BeanWiringInfo buildWiringInfo(Object beanInstance, Configurable annotation) {
        if (!Autowire.NO.equals(annotation.autowire())) {
            return new BeanWiringInfo(annotation.autowire().value(), annotation.dependencyCheck());
        }
        else {
            if (!"".equals(annotation.value())) {
                // explicitly specified bean name
                return new BeanWiringInfo(annotation.value(), false);
            }
            else {
                // default bean name
                return new BeanWiringInfo(getDefaultBeanName(beanInstance), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'name' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.transformedBeanName(BeanFactoryUtils.java:72) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1109) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:970) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.SpringViewDisplayPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(SpringViewDisplayPostProcessor.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1594) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:400) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.configureBean(AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj:63) ~[spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$before$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$1$e854fa65(AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj:79) ~[spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.scipionyx.butterflyeffect.frontend.configuration.ui.view.AboutView.<init>(AboutView.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone knows what can be wrong on this configuration ?

Your help us much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to understand why, but it seems that removing the `autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME` from the @Configuration seems to solve the problem.

Now the Class looks like this:

```
@UIScope()
@SpringComponent(value = AboutView.VIEW_NAME)
@SpringView(name = AboutView.VIEW_NAME)

//
@Configurable(value = AboutView.VIEW_NAME)
public class AboutView extends AbstractView {
```